# Is the right value's constructor called in initialization?

Tags: c++, rvalue

For example,

```
struct A {};

struct B
{
    B(A&& a)
       : mA(std::move(a)) // Is A's constructor called here?
    {}

    A&& mA;
};
```

Is `A`'s constructor called in the initialization list of `B`? Or it's like a reference implemented by a pointer?

Comment: Create a constructor and try it: A:A() { cout << "A's constructor\n";}

Comment: Thanks. Should be `A:A(A const& a) {cout << "A's constructor\n";}` or `A:A(A&& a) {cout << "A's constructor\n";}`.

Comment: I'd put both in place, with distinct cout strings so you know what's what. And the move constructor as well. Oh actually what you've written there (in last comment) is the copy constructor and the move constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; `mA` is not an object but merely a reference, so there is nothing to construct.